# WSO2 Developer Studio - CEP Bucket

Tags: wso2, complex-event-processing, wso2-integration-studio

Is there any way to give some syntax or context help for writing EPL queries while creating buckets using WSO2 Developer Studio ?
Is there any EPL query editor exist outside WSO2 stack ?

Comment: @Maninda - Can you please provide update on above question ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently there is no such tool you can use to write WSO2 CEP EPL queries outside of WSO2 Stack but we will provide support to write EPL queries in the CEP editor source view in a future release of WSO2 developer Studio IDE.

Until then you need to use the CEP editor design view and enter the EPL queries manually.

/Harshana